# Align preprocessors structurally in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, format

new to stackoverflow and somewhat new to visual studio - Used it many years ago but switched to CLion, but now am returning for a directx project. I can't seem to figure out how to make visual studio format my preprocessors the way I prefer and am used to from CLion.

Ideally I'd like to format them structurally, for example:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
    #define DBGPRINT(fmt, ...) printf(fmt, __VA_ARGS__)
#else
    #define DBGPRINT(...)
#endif
```

however, Visual Studio ends up formatting it to be all left aligned:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
#define DBGPRINT(fmt, ...) printf(fmt, __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define DBGPRINT(...)
#endif
```

I know Visual Studio 2019 now has support for clang-format which could solve the issue, but clang would then reformat other parts of my code I don't want it to (would rather not have to add //clang-format (off|on) everywhere). So I am hoping there is a way to do this without resorting to clang?

Comment: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html

Comment: @JesperJuhl I know about clang, but it doesn't support certain formatting rules that I like to use, such as keeping my formatting on array initializer lists and such (at least not that I've found after hours of googling). Or is it possible to make Visual Studio mix and match for the formatting rules by chance?

Comment: I suggest that you could set your own code format through `Visual Studio Tools->options->Text Editor->C/C++->Formatting`.

Comment: @BarrnetChou I've tried, however all preprocessor options seem to make it all left aligned like the example in my post

Comment: In my opinion, I am afraid that there is no way to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon this thread trying to find similar request as that of OT for VSCode. I found an option to align preprocessors. Need to change the below setting.
C_Cpp › Vc Format › Indent: Preprocessor
from "leftmostColumn" to "oneLeft" or "none" as per the requirement.
Might be worth a try to see if similar setting is there in Visual Studio too.